# map if-then-else to probability

Tags: algorithm, probability

I need an algorithm to transform game rules (p&p role playing) to probabilities, specifically conditional constructs built from if-then-else with conditions made of the boolean (not,and,or) and relational operators (==,>=,<=,<,>) and dice rolls and boolean values.

Example:

```
var a = diceRoll(d8,d10,d12) // a shaker full of dices
                             // a 8 sides, a 10 sided and a 12 sided dice
                             // values added together
var w = true
var result = (
  if (a>=20) then 10.3994
  else if (a>=14 and w) then 8.23
  else if (a>=8 and diceRoll(d6)>3) then 5.22
  else 0
)
```

should be transformed programatically to a formula for the expected average result like

```
var result = diceProbabilityGreaterThan(a,20)*10.3994 
+(diceProbabilityGreaterThan(a,14)-diceProbabilityGreaterThan(a,20))*8.23 
+ ..
```

I know how to map a single relational operator on a single diceRoll to a probability (diceProbabilityGreaterThan), and I know how I could transform this specific simple example by hand, but I have problems to find a general transformation scheme for any given rule. The hard part in this problem to me are the dependend probabilities (like a>20 ... a>10).

More background:

- I know that I could use a monte carlo method, but I tried it and it's
  too slow for my use case.
- The rules are allready data structures, so
  there is no parsing required.
- The dices may be exploding, meaning a 6
  sided dice falling on 6 will be rolled again and adding up, so the
  maximum shaker result is not bounded by an finite number.
- The rules contain no loop control structures like while or for, they just form
  an maybe nested if-then-else-tree.
- The boolean and number values in
  the conditions are constants.
- The solution can be limited to just one
  dependend probability variable (like a in the example), but I'm
  interested also in the existence of a general solution for any number
  of depended variable.

*This question is a clone from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842458/map-if-then-else-to-probability because it was marked there as offtopic.*

Comment: Can't you just create functions like: function(int a, int b) { if (a==b) return 1; else return 0; } Then you multiply each term with that function if you want it to contribute or not to the probability? Maybe I misunderstood your problem, sorry if that is the case.

Comment: @mancuernita: it's more complicated if the probabilities are bounded, how to deal with that? It's not simply addition or multiplication then.

Comment: What do you mean by bounded? I'm proposing something like: p += function(compare(a, cond, operator))*diceProbabilityGreaterThan(a,cond)*probability_value. That, you can put it an a foreach loop or similar and go over all your a values, matching them to the condition, and adding the probability if condition is fulfilled.

Comment: in the example above case 1) if a>=20 and case 2) if a>=14, the probability of case 2) needs to take into account the probability of 1) because 2) includes 1). A possible solution was sketched by dtldarek in math.stackexchange: "You could translate your code into state-based system and calculate the probabilities via linear algebra (similarly to Markov chains), but it is going to be both slow and complicated."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is calculate the expected value of the function. This can be done recursively.

I assume you have the rules in a tree-like data structure. Then the initial call would just be `root.CalculateExpectedValue()`.

There are three kinds of nodes:

1. Leaf nodes (that specify an actual value). `CalculateExpectedValue()` should return this very value for leaf nodes.
2. Variable definitions. These nodes have one child and return `child.CalculateExpectedValue()`. However, they have to introduce a variable declaration along with its probability mass function. The probability mass functions of all active variables must be passed as a parameter to `CalculateExpectedValue()`. More information on the probability mass function below.
3. Decisions. These nodes have two children. The probability of both cases can be calculated, given the probability mass functions of active variables. Then these nodes should return `p * trueChild.CalculateExpectedValue() + (1 - p) * falseChild.CalculateExpectedValue()`. Furthermore, they have to adjust the probability mass function of involved variables.

A probability mass function for a variable defines how likely it is for this variable to become a certain value. For a simple six-sided dice, this would be `1 -> 1/6, 2 -> 1/6, 3 -> 1/6 ...`. It is probably easiest to store this function as a dictionary or map.

For the `diceRoll` function with more than one dice, we have to be able to add two probability mass function (e.g. pmf for d8 + pmf for d10, and later to d12). In order to do so, we create a new empty pmf. For each pair of elements of both input distributions, we calculate the resulting sum (`element1.Value + element2.Value`) and its probability (`element1.probability * element2.probability`).

Now we can create and modify PMFs for variable declaration nodes. We still need the behavior of decision nodes.

The first thing is to calculate the probability of a decision. That's rather easy. Pick the PMF of the according variable, iterate all entries and sum the probability if the condition holds for the element.

For the `true` child, we have to modify the PMF in that way that all entries where the condition is false are removed. For the `false` child, we have to remove the other entries. Afterwards we have to re-normalize the PMF (i.e. divide by sum of remaining probabilities). Be sure to create new PMFs. You don't want these modifications to intervene with other parts of the tree.

You could also propagate the cumulative probability to the leaf nodes. However, this is not necessary to calculate the expected value.

Comment: One missing point: the dice explodes, so it's not possible to enumerate them. I'm thinking about using a precalculated probability-table (by monte-carlo) for the partial sum of the pmf over the >= operator (diceGT). Then the modification of the pmf (for the active variables in decisions) would be equivalent to interval subtraction over diceGT (for example a>=10 and not a>=20 is the interval [10,20[ and the probability is diceGT(a,20)-diceGT(a,10)), so a list of intervals, some interval arithemtic and mapping a list of intervals to a probability may do it

Comment: You could model the exposion with an appropriate PMF. However, this is only possible up to a certain number of explosions (maybe one or two). More explosions are that unlikely that they should not change the expected value significantly. The interval might not be appropriate for all cases. The sum of two dice is not equally distributed (values in the middle are more likely than at the edges). That's why I suggested a map, which allows greatest flexibility.

Comment: How does subtraction of diceGT at the interval borders depend on the probability distribution of the dicesum? I calculated some examples and get the same results. What did I miss?

Comment: I probably misunderstood you. If you mean precalculating the partial sums, then this is of course possible.

Comment: The PMF and partial sum of PMF can be precalculated very accurately with Troll (http://topps.diku.dk/torbenm/troll.msp), in my case there are only about 150 possible dice-sets (shakers). Calculation of PMFs can be very expensive for shakers with many dices (exponential), see http://www.mindspring.com/~donp/ed_prob.html